# Login screen using for loops and arrays

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, c#-3.0

I am meant to make a quiz for A level coursework and in this quiz I have a player registration screen which takes the username, password, player icon number and date and time and saves it to a text file.

I have a player login screen which is supposed to take the values put into username and password text boxes, turn them into strings, create an array from the text file and then checks if the player username and corresponding password are found. If they are found the quiz is supposed to advance to the first question and if they are not found a label will be displayed saying 'user not found'.

My problem is that as long as there is writing in the text file the quiz will advance to the first question. I can't seem to get it to work correctly.

```
private void btnLogin_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string userName = txtExistingUserName.Text.ToString();
        string userPassword = txtExistingPassword.Text.ToString();
        bool bUserFound = false;
        lblUserNotFound.Visible = false;

        string filePath = "../../TextFiles/txtPlayer.txt";
        string[] fileLinesToRead = File.ReadAllLines(filePath);

        for (int i = 0; i < fileLinesToRead.Count(); i = i + 7)
        {
            for (int y = i; y < i + 7; y++)
            {
                if (fileLinesToRead[y].Contains(userName))
                {
                    if (fileLinesToRead[y].Contains(userPassword))
                    {
                        bUserFound = true;
                        break;
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    bUserFound = false;
                }
            }
        }

        if (bUserFound)
        {
            PlayerDetails.playerName = userName;
            PlayerDetails.playerPassword = userPassword;

            Random rndInt = new Random();
            int random = rndInt.Next(1, 3);

            switch (random)
            {
                case 1:
                    Form myNextScreen = new frmQuestion1();
                    myNextScreen.ShowDialog();
                    //this.Close();
                    break;
                case 2:
                    Form myNextScreenAlt = new frmQuestion1Alt();
                    myNextScreenAlt.ShowDialog();
                    //this.Close();
                    break;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            lblUserNotFound.Visible = true;
        }

        }
```

Comment: What does a line in the text file look like? You shouldn't use string.contains to compare a password. Also, you should load the text file into a dictionary at application load and then get the password from the dictionary and use == or string.compare depending on how you handle types, case sensitivity, etc.

Comment: im fairly new at c# so can you explain what you mean. This is for school so we are just handed a book and told to use it to make a quiz but the book is terrible. A line in the text file looks like this: Test,123,3,25/01/2017 11:15:05

Comment: Obviously you are just a student but note that storing passwords in plaintext *is a terrible idea*. You want to store a cryptographically secure salted hash, every time.

Comment: A good place to start would be looking into the String.Split function. There is some example code here that could help: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b873y76a(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 0):

Declare a dictionary somewhere accessible to your form.

```
public static Dictionary<string, string> _users;
```

Declare a load user method to call at application start.

```
private const string FilePath = "../../TextFiles/txtPlayer.txt";

private static void LoadUsers()
{
    _users = new Dictionary<string, string>();

    using (var sr = new StreamReader(FilePath))
    {
        string line = sr.ReadLine();
        string[] lineArray = line?.Split(',');
        if (lineArray?[0] != null && lineArray[1] != null)
            _users.Add(lineArray[0].ToString(), lineArray[1].ToString());
    }
}
```

Declare a validate password method to return true when the user exists and the password is correct, false otherwise.

```
private bool PasswordIsValid(string userName, string password)
{
    string expectedPassword = _users[userName];
    if (password == null || expectedPassword != password)
        return false;
    return true;
}
```

To use in your code, just call:

```
If(PasswordIsValid(userName, password))
    ...
```